# How to modify calender in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, calendar

How to modify the calendar in flutter? I attached the image below, any package
**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can user flutter_calendar_carousel calender to achieve it. and then add a custom widget at bottom with color markings.
here:- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel